# Pulling an disaggregated blocks of data Set into R

Tags: regex, r, csv, read.table

I have a csv file that is unusually laid out. The data is not a contigous block at the top. The csv file can be characterized as such:

```
Comment Strings
Empty row
Comment String

[Desired Data with 10 columns and an undetermined number of rows]

Empty Row

Comment String 

[Desired Data with 10 columns and an undetermined number of rows]

Empty Row

Comment String
```

[Desired Data with 10 columns and an undetermined number of columns]

```
.... and so on and so forth.
```

As stated. Each block of data has a random number of rows.

What would be the best way to pull this data into R? The `read.table/read.csv` can only do so much.

```
 read.table("C:\\Users\\Riemmman\\Desktop\\Historical Data\\datafile.csv",header=F,sep=",",skip=15,blank.lines.skip=T)
```

Comment: Please post a small sample/example of your data. What is your desired output? The first 10 columns of each data section? While you can do text processing in R, it's more quickly done in other utilities like awk or sed.

Comment: Are there common headers for the "Desired Data" blocks? Also, I assume that you meant "undetermined number of *rows*".

Comment: Yes, they all have the same number of rows with the same named columns. My problem is telling R, "Hey.. the first contiguous block is here, the second is here, skip over this part, the third is there, etc.."

Comment: Is there a way to just load the entire thing into R and format it in there? So I would load the entire file, which would include the data and text, and then clean it up inside of R.

Comment: @jessica, yes. `readLines` would let you load the entire file. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20811459/1270695) for a possible solution within R.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might be able to use a combination of `readLines` and `grep`/`grepl` to help you figure out which lines to read.

Here's an example. The first part is just to make up some sample data.

#### Create some sample data.

```
x <- tempfile(pattern="myFile", fileext=".csv")

cat("junk comment strings",
    "",
    "another junk comment string",
    "This,Is,My,Data",
    "1,2,3,4",
    "5,6,7,8",
    "",
    "back to comments",
    "This,Is,My,Data",
    "12,13,14,15",
    "15,16,17,18",
    "19,20,21,22", file = x, sep = "\n")
```

#### Step 1: Use `readLines()` to get the data into R

In this step, we'll also drop the lines that we are not interested in. The logic is that we are only interested in lines where there is information in the form of (for a four-column dataset):

> something comma something comma something comma something

---

```
## Read the data into R
## Replace "con" with the actual path to your file
A <- readLines(con = x)

## Find and extract the lines where there are "data".
## My example dataset only has 4 columns.
## Modify for your actual dataset.
A <- A[grepl(paste(rep(".*", 4), collapse=","), A)]
```

#### Step 2: Identify the data ranges

```
## Identify the header rows. -1 for use with read.csv
HeaderRows <- grep("^This,Is", A)-1

## Identify the number of rows per data group
N <- c(diff(HeaderRows)-1, length(A)-1)
```

#### Step 3: Read the data in

Use the data range information to specify how many lines to skip before reading, and how many lines to read.

```
myData <- lapply(seq_along(HeaderRows), 
       function(x) read.csv(text = A, header = TRUE, 
                            nrows = N[x], skip = HeaderRows[x]))
myData
# [[1]]
#   This Is My Data
# 1    1  2  3    4
# 2    5  6  7    8
# 
# [[2]]
#   This Is My Data
# 1   12 13 14   15
# 2   15 16 17   18
# 3   19 20 21   22
```

---

If you want all of these in one `data.frame` instead of a `list`, use:

```
final <- do.call(rbind, myData)
```

Comment: Where does the OP say there are multiple header rows in the file? The solution can be much simple if that assumption is not made. Don't you think?

Comment: @asb, I assumed that from [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20810874/pulling-an-disaggregated-blocks-of-data-set-into-r/20811459?noredirect=1#comment31203836_20810874). Of course, yes, the solution can be made much simpler if that assumption is not made.

Comment: The headers are the same for each contiguous block

Comment: @jessica, then this answer should work, unless your data differs from the scenario you describe.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Ananda. When you were loading the data using the x <- tempfile() and the cat(), how did the data using the cat() attach itself to x??

Comment: @jessica, the `cat` and `tempfile` steps in this answer were just to create a reproducible example. `tempfile` creates a (surprise!) temporary file, and R can read/write to it as if it were a file in a directory in your OS. `cat` by default just prints things to the console, but here, with the `file` argument, I have written it to this `tempfile` instead, so that we can replicate the process of reading data in from the OS with R.

Answer (score 1):

I just recently faced a problem like this. My solution was to use awk to separate out the different types of rows, load them into different tables in a dbms and use sql to create a flat file for loading into R.

Or maybe you can awk out only your desired data and load that, if you don't care about the comment strings.

Comment: I don't know awk. Would be to difficult to learn at this point. Is there a way to specify the excel data range when pulling in data into R? So tell R, pull the data from A1:Q352 for example?

Comment: For what you need to do it's not difficult, but it is not a standard tool for windows like it is for unix. If all the data you want is in one range in excel, why not just edit the excel file and save as csv? If you need more help please post a small section of the real data.

Answer (score 1):

Using the data generated by @Ananda Mahto,

```
file = x # change for the actual file name
alldata = readLines(file) # read all data
# count the fields in data (separated by comma)
nfields = count.fields(file=textConnection(alldata), sep=",", blank.lines.skip=FALSE) 
# asumme data has the 'mode' of the number of fields (can change for the actual number of colums)
dataFields = as.numeric(names(table(nfields))[which.max(table(nfields))]) 

alldata = alldata[nfields == dataFields] # read data lines only
header = alldata[1] # the header
alldata = c(header, alldata[alldata!=header]) # remove the extra headers
datos = read.csv(text=alldata) # read the data

  This Is My Data
1    1  2  3    4
2    5  6  7    8
3   12 13 14   15
4   15 16 17   18
5   19 20 21   22
```

Comment: You can shorten this a bit: `A <- readLines(con = x); nFields <- count.fields(file = textConnection(A), sep=",", blank.lines.skip = FALSE); A <- A[nFields == max(nFields)]; read.csv(text = A[-grep("^This,Is", A)[-1]])`

Comment: I want the "mode" of the number of fields, not the maximum (maybe a lot of commas in the comments). Also, we don't know what the headers are, but all the data blocks have the same headers. I'm using that.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, I used your suggestion to read the data only once, thanks.